# How to check and remove the event if already exist with vanilla javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, preventdefault

I am performing a task where i need to reload the function again but i do not want to add same event with same function so i need to listen the elements events first and if it is not exist i need to add it if event already exist i need to prevent it from happening.

My DOM i like this.

```
<a href='#clicked' id='toggle_bars' data-gonext='1'>next</next>

$('#toggle_bars').click(function(){
// some argument
})

// for page one
<a href='#clicked' id='toggle_bars_again' data-goback='1'>next</next>
$('#toggle_bars_again').click(function(){
// some argument
})
// for page one
```

i do not want to reload the page
when user click on `#toggle_bars` he need to go back and reload its function when i load the  `#toggle_bars_again` the function repeat itself i want to listen its events and prevent it from happening.

i also use methods like `return false` `event.preventDefault()` `event.stopPropogation`

FYI : I know that this is may be a bad practice but this is a very old code-base and i do not want to redo it again.

Comment: The issue isn't quite clear, but it sounds like the [`one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one) method may help you

Comment: The events jQuery stores are not publicly available, you can't check if an element has an event attached or not. It sounds like you could save a state of the events, or use `one()` as Rory has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

"he need to go back and reload its function when I load the #toggle_bars_again the function repeat itself I want to listen its events and prevent it from happening." what are you trying to say its not clear.
if you want to prevent the page from reloading remove href and in here:

```
   $('#toggle_bars').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's clearly what you search, but if you need to connect the same event again on the same element, you can do something like that :

```
$("element").off("click").on("click", function() {})
```

And if it's on an other element, just do an off on the first and then connect your event to the second element

Jquery's one() method could be a solution too